# Syntax of recursive variadic function in Scala

Tags: scala, recursion, variadic-functions

I'm learning Scala and I just faced variadic functions. It's almost all ok on the example below I wrote:

```
object Sscce {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    printStrings("Hello", "Scala", "here", "I", "am");
  }

  def printStrings(ss: String*): Unit = {
    if (!ss.isEmpty) {
      println(ss.head)
      printStrings(ss.tail: _*)
    }
  }

}
```

I understand that `String*` means a variable list of strings and that `ss` is mapped to a `Seq` type. I also assume that a `Seq` cannot passed to a variadic function so in the recursive call of `printStrings` something has to be done with `ss`.

Question is: what is the exact meaning of `: _*`? It seems something like a cast to me (since there's the `:` symbol)

Comment: Note that none of those are functions, they are methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a *sequence argument* (see the second-to-last paragraph in [section 6.6 *Function Applications* of the *Scala Language Specification*](http://Scala-Lang.Org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#function-applications)).

It deliberately resembles [*Type Ascription*](http://Scala-Lang.Org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#typed-expressions) syntax. In an argument list, it basically means the exact opposite of what [*Repeated Parameters*](http://Scala-Lang.Org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#repeated-parameters) mean in a parameter list. Repeated parameters mean "take all the leftover arguments and collect them into a single `Seq`", whereas sequence arguments mean "take this single `Seq` and pass its elements as individual arguments".