# (Scala) How to convert List into a Seq

Tags: scala

I have a function like

```
def myFunction(i:Int*) = i.map(a => println(a))
```

but I have a List of Int's.

```
val myList:List[Int] = List(1,2,3,4)

Desired output:
1
2
3
4
```

How can I programmatically convert myList so it can be inserted into myFunction?

Comment: Unrelated: If you are using a side effecting function like `println` you can use `foreach` instead of `map`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28527971/2988

Comment: Your question is not really "how to convert a `List` to a `Seq`", because the answer to that would be: call `toSeq` on the list. It's about how to invoke a varargs method when you have a `List`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your desired input and output, you want to pass a `List` where a varargs argument is expected.
A varargs method can receive zero or more arguments of same type.
The varargs parameter has type of `Array[T]` actually.
But you can pass any `Seq` to it, by using "varargs ascription/expansion" (IDK if there is an official name for this):

```
myFunction(myList: _*)
```

Comment: Thank you. It would have taken me eons to figure this out on my own.

Comment: could you please explain your answer as well?

Comment: @ManuChadha I elaborated bit more on it. I actually expected it to be closed as duplicate... LOL